# why asp .net mvc web api does not support custom operations?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, http, asp.net-web-api

I don't know if I am missing something obvious.

I can see that asp .net web api supports standard Get(), GetById(), Add, Update, Delete operations. But it does not support some custom operations/actions like for example  "Get_CustomDataForModel", "Do_SomePostWork" or "Do_somecalc_and_return_a_list" any such custom operations.

I have tried searching for this question, but couldn't get a direct answer. If this is a duplicate, pls give me the right link.

Is this because HTTP REST requests must only support one method each per url for GET, POST, DELETE, PUT etc.,?

Am I missing something obvious while it supports it and I don't see it?

Is there a way to add let's say 30 different actions with 15 get and 15 posts? (PS: I know having 30 actions inside a controller is a bad idea, but asking just for the sake of understanding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Web API supports HTTP method based routing. But it does support RPC-style routing based on action methods. Look at the section "Routing by Action Name" in http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api. BTW, it is possible to have 30 different action methods in a controller but won't it be a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: Yup, I understand the nightmare :) But why I put the question is to understand if it is possible. Thankks for your answer.